# how to sort array like mysql

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

how to sort array which is the same with datebase data?

I requested google analytics datas, the datas is an larget array , I want to join the array with some other fields from my local database , then I extend the large array again. Now I want to sort the large array which is the same with using my sql like this:

```
select * from ga_table where ...
select * from ga_table order by age
select * from ga_table group by name
```

my array now is like:

```
$arr=array(
    'header'=>array('name','age','money'),
    'values'=>array(
        array('jimmy',20,30),
        array('tina',18,12),
        array('darcy',19,50),
    )
);
```

but now I had a large array not a db table , then how to sort the array ?
[image]

Comment: Maybe add in how you want it sorted? Name, values?

Comment: Something like [PHPLinq](https://phplinq.codeplex.com/)

Comment: take a look [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php)

Comment: PHP has built in sort functions but it depends on what you want to do exactly

Comment: How you want it to be sorted? by name or age or money ?

Comment: asort(); arsort(); krsort(); etc all are PHP inbuilt functions used to sort the array. For better understanding you can visi the link http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can try `array_multisort`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php

```
foreach ($arr['values'] as $key => $row) {
    $name[$key]  = $row[0];
    $age[$key] = $row[1];
    $money[$key] = $row[3];
}
```

now if you want to sort by name in ASC you can:

```
array_multisort($name, SORT_ASC, $arr['values']);
```

or by name DESC:

```
array_multisort($name, SORT_DESC, $arr['values']);
```

or age ASC:

```
array_multisort($age, SORT_ASC, $arr['values']);
```

or age DESC and name ASC

```
array_multisort($age, SORT_DESC, $name, SORT_ASC, $arr['values']);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 asort(); 
 arsort();
 krsort();
```

etc.. all are PHP inbuilt functions used to sort the array.

For better understanding you can visi the link http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @mamdouh alramadan!

I wrote a helper function to sort array like MySQL

```
function arrayOrderBy(array $items, array $orderBy)
{
    if (empty($items) || empty($orderBy)) {
        return $items;
    }

    $multisortArgs = [];

    foreach ($orderBy as $field => $direction) {
        $columnValues = array_column($items, $field);

        if (empty($columnValues)) {
            continue;
        }

        $multisortArgs[] = $columnValues;
        $multisortArgs[] = strtoupper($direction) === 'ASC' ? SORT_ASC : SORT_DESC;
    }

    if (empty($multisortArgs)) {
        return $items;
    }

    $multisortArgs[] = &$items;

    call_user_func_array('array_multisort', $multisortArgs);

    return $items;
}
```

#### Usage

```
$data[] = array('volume' => 67, 'edition' => 7);
$data[] = array('volume' => 86, 'edition' => 1);
$data[] = array('volume' => 85, 'edition' => 6);
$data[] = array('volume' => 98, 'edition' => 2);
$data[] = array('volume' => 86, 'edition' => 6);
$data[] = array('volume' => 67, 'edition' => 2);

$sorted = arrayOrderBy($data, ['volume' => 'desc', 'edition' => 'asc']);

print_r($sorted);
```

And the output is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [volume] => 98
            [edition] => 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [volume] => 86
            [edition] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [volume] => 86
            [edition] => 6
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [volume] => 85
            [edition] => 6
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [volume] => 67
            [edition] => 2
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [volume] => 67
            [edition] => 7
        )

)
```