# Why/how does this array_multisort() work?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, array-multisort

**Code:**

```
<?php
$data = array(
    'uid3' => array(
        'name' => 'Unique ID 3',
        'count' => 11
    ),
    'uid1' => array(
        'name' => 'Unique ID 1',
        'count' => 11
    ),
    'uid2' => array(
        'name' => 'Unique ID 2',
        'count' => 15
    ),
    'uid4' => array(
        'name' => 'Unique ID 4',
        'count' => 13
    )
);

$counts = array_map( function( $v ){
    return $v[ 'count' ];
}, $data );

$names = array_map( function( $v ){
    return $v[ 'name' ];
}, $data );

print_r( $counts );
print_r( $names );

array_multisort(
    $counts, SORT_DESC, SORT_NUMERIC,
    $names, SORT_ASC, SORT_STRING,
    $data
);

print_r( $data );
```

**Output:**

```
// $counts
Array
(
    [uid3] => 11
    [uid1] => 11
    [uid2] => 15
    [uid4] => 13
)

// $names
Array
(
    [uid3] => Unique ID 3
    [uid1] => Unique ID 1
    [uid2] => Unique ID 2
    [uid4] => Unique ID 4
)

// $data after sorting
Array
(
    [uid2] => Array
        (
            [name] => Unique ID 2
            [count] => 15
        )

    [uid4] => Array
        (
            [name] => Unique ID 4
            [count] => 13
        )

    [uid1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Unique ID 1
            [count] => 11
        )

    [uid3] => Array
        (
            [name] => Unique ID 3
            [count] => 11
        )

)
```

---

**Question:**

How did `array_multisort()` know to apply the sorting result of `$counts` to the `count` sub-key of each item in the multi-dimensional array `$data`?

*Likewise for `$names` to the `name` sub-key.*

---

**Bonus:**

If `$names, SORT_ASC, SORT_STRING,` is commented out of the function call then `uid3` still ends up after `uid1`. Why?

---

I've been reading the following resources but I cannot wrap my mind as to how this applies to my example:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php

[how php array_multisort work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9093664/2191572)

[how to sort array like mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19654966/2191572)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't going to post this as an answer, but I needed just a few extra characters.

I can't say definitively how it *does* do it on a technical level, but I think addressing specifically "How did `array_multisort()` know to apply the sorting result of `$counts` to the count sub-key", the answer is "it didn't".  Change the sub-keys and you get the same result. Maybe I'm not reading your question the way you intended, but it seems as if you're asking how does it know to look at the sub-key values of `$data` and then do the sorting. But it doesn't. It looks at how `$names` was sorted (which looks at how `$counts` was sorted) and applies the same sort to the *primary* keys of `$data`.  Meaning it looks at what original position was moved to what new position.  The fact that your first array is made from the values of one sub-key and the second was made from another sub-key is irrelevant.  Hand build those arrays in the same order and you'll get the same results.

For the bonus, I'd say it's related to "If two members compare as equal, their relative order in the sorted array is undefined.".  So it's more just coincidence than anything else.

Comment: I think you've hit the nail squarely on the head with "applies the same sort to the *primary* keys of `$data`". After further testing I can confirm what you've answered. This make me wonder though, is `array_multisort()` a viable substitute for SQL's `ORDER BY` clause?

Comment: I've managed to achieve a multisort by using `uasort()` and it does not produce the "bonus" behavior. Gahh, decisions, decisions! For future Googlers, see https://www.the-art-of-web.com/php/sortarray/#section_3 ;-)

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I suppose if you were doing some sort of challenge where you were explicitly prohibited from using `ORDER BY`. I don't think I'd ever _choose_ to use it instead of `ORDER BY` though. It's not nearly as transparent what's happening and the more columns you need to sort, the more complicated it becomes. And as a fun note, even [the comments in the source code](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/array.c#L5713) refer to the underlying sorting as "magic". Yes, I also tested the simple sort functions and noticed that too. They're not kidding when they say "undefined"

Comment: Ha, magic indeed! My use case for mimicking SQL's sorting syntactic sugar is simple. I am pulling in an RSS feed, converting it to an array, and by default need to sort it by `pubDate desc, title asc`. I am also building in the option to accept sorting order via `$_GET` so things could get "wild". e.g `?sort[title]=desc&sort[pubDate]=asc`

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Ah, okay, that would make sense then. Even the PHP manual gives sorting DB results as the 3rd usage example.

Comment: I noticed that in the manual as well. I might decide to benchmark the `uasort()` equivalent to `array_multisort()` in the future just out of curiosity but I think I can move on with my life for the time being. Thanks for the insightful answer and discussion!

Comment: Glad to help.  Any time.  It's nice to actually have an interesting question :)